# convert int? to int in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, integer, duration

i get int? variable from SharedPreferences class with getInt() method.
I have to put this int? as a parameter for Duration Object but i need to have an int.
What can I do?
This is the code:

```
int? duration = ParametersHelper.getDuration();
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: duration));
```

This is getDuration() method in ParametersHelper:

```
static int? getDuration() {
    return _pref.getInt("Duration");
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either override this behavior by explicitly telling the dart compiler that although the variable can be nullable I guarantee that it's not null, be careful when using it though.

```
int duration = ParametersHelper.getDuration()!; // using the ! operator
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: duration));
```

The second option is to use the ?? operator which means if the value is null assign another value

```
int duration = ParametersHelper.getDuration() ?? 2; // if null assign 2
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: duration));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this :

```
int? duration = ParametersHelper.getDuration();
Future.delayed( Duration(milliseconds: duration!));
```

as you can write `null assertion operator (!)`

Answer (score 0):

'int?' means that the value can be either int or null. SharedPreferences returns 'int?' in

```
_pref.getInt("Duration")
```

because in case there is no value with key "Duration" stored with

```
_pref.setInt("Duration", 4)
```

in that case it will return null.

If you are sure that there is a int stored in a key named "Duration" in SharedPreferences before calling getDuration() function, then you can use "!" (conditional property access operator) in dart.

```
int? duration = getDuration();
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: duration!));
```

"!" is a dart operator for conversion from a nullable to a non-nullable type.
Use it only if you are absolutely sure that the value will never be null, i.e. there is always a int stored in key "Duration" in preferences before calling it, and do not confuse it with the conditional property access operator(?).